# Trouble building git-credential-libsecret: unknown type name ‘SecretService’

Tags: c, git, github, makefile, header-files

I'm trying to compile the `git-credential-libsecret.c` in `/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret` by running `sudo make` on the `Makefile` there.

However, this fails with the following output:

```
gcc -g -O2 -Wall  -pthread -I/usr/include/libsecret-1 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include   -o git-credential-libsecret.o -c git-credential-libsecret.c
git-credential-libsecret.c: In function ‘keyring_get’:
git-credential-libsecret.c:87:2: error: unknown type name ‘SecretService’
  SecretService *service = NULL;
  ^
git-credential-libsecret.c:95:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘secret_service_get_sync’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  service = secret_service_get_sync(0, NULL, &error);
  ^
git-credential-libsecret.c:95:10: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  service = secret_service_get_sync(0, NULL, &error);
          ^
git-credential-libsecret.c:103:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘secret_service_search_sync’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  items = secret_service_search_sync(service,
  ^
git-credential-libsecret.c:106:9: error: ‘SECRET_SEARCH_LOAD_SECRETS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         SECRET_SEARCH_LOAD_SECRETS | SECRET_SEARCH_UNLOCK,
         ^
git-credential-libsecret.c:106:9: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
git-credential-libsecret.c:106:38: error: ‘SECRET_SEARCH_UNLOCK’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         SECRET_SEARCH_LOAD_SECRETS | SECRET_SEARCH_UNLOCK,
                                      ^
git-credential-libsecret.c:117:3: error: unknown type name ‘SecretItem’
   SecretItem *item;
   ^
git-credential-libsecret.c:118:3: error: unknown type name ‘SecretValue’
   SecretValue *secret;
   ^
git-credential-libsecret.c:122:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘secret_item_get_secret’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   secret = secret_item_get_secret(item);
   ^
git-credential-libsecret.c:122:10: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   secret = secret_item_get_secret(item);
          ^
git-credential-libsecret.c:123:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘secret_item_get_attributes’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   attributes = secret_item_get_attributes(item);
   ^
git-credential-libsecret.c:123:14: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   attributes = secret_item_get_attributes(item);
              ^
git-credential-libsecret.c:131:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘secret_value_get_text’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   s = secret_value_get_text(secret);
   ^
git-credential-libsecret.c:131:5: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   s = secret_value_get_text(secret);
     ^
git-credential-libsecret.c:138:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘secret_value_unref’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   secret_value_unref(secret);
   ^
make: *** [git-credential-libsecret.o] Error 1
```

From what I can tell the errors are stemming from the `unknown type name` issues and them spiralling out as the `unknown type`s are used "incorrectly" later on.

As near as I can tell, however, the types are perfectly well defined in the locations provided in the source files:

```
grep -Enr "#include.*secret\.h" git-credential-libsecret.c 
30:#include <libsecret/secret.h>
```

Per the `gcc` call, this will be found at `/usr/include/libsecret-1`, and indeed:

```
ls /usr/include/libsecret-1/libsecret
secret-attributes.h  secret-enum-types.h  secret-item.h      secret-paths.h   secret-schema.h   secret-service.h  secret-value.h
secret-collection.h  secret.h             secret-password.h  secret-prompt.h  secret-schemas.h  secret-types.h
```

This header itself doesn't define `SecretService` (`grep -E "^typedef" secret.h` gives nothing), because the `SecretService` is defined in `secret-service.h`:

```
grep -nE "^typedef.*SecretService;" /usr/include/libsecret-1/libsecret/secret-service.h 
53:typedef struct _SecretService        SecretService;
```

And `secret-service` is included in `secret.h`:

```
grep -En "^#include.*service" /usr/include/libsecret-1/libsecret/secret.h 
40:#include <libsecret/secret-service.h>
```

Similar investigations yield the same for `SecretItem` and `SecretValue`.

Am I missing something? Why doesn't the file build as expected?

Comment: The `-I` options *look* OK but make sure that gcc really is reading that particular file (check the preprocessed output or generated dependency output). If it *is* reading that particular file, see if the type definition in the header is protected behind some `#ifdef` or `#ifndef`: you might have to select `-D` options at compile time to get the data structures.

Comment: Thanks @torek. A bit of a newbie here -- your first point is the `-M` option? i.e. I should be able to answer the first concern by compiling with `-M -MF dep-out` and then looking for the headers I cited in `dep-out`? (if so, then confirmed -- the `-I` is working correctly)

Comment: As to the hidden `#ifdef` possibility, it seems no. You can see a copy of the file here... seems straightforward enough and have tracked down a few of the other types to make sure they're included as well (seems so). I don't follow what you mean about using `-D`

Comment: A lot of today's C code headers do things like `#ifdef _POSIX_C_SOURCE`, so if you compile with `cc foo.c` you get functions A, B, and C; if you compile with cc -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE` you get functions A and B, but then get the Posix-speciifc variant of C instead of (or in addition to) function C. (Your "copy of the file here", if it was supposed to be a link, isn't.)

Comment: And yes, I meant that you could look at -M stuff, or—more thorough and might track down where things are going wrong—run `cc -E` to get the preprocessed output and look at the various `#line` directives.